# Apply jquery validation to dropdown select before submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can I apply the form validation to the dropdown country code list? The list must remain a `<li>` list. It needs to validate both the numerical input(which it already does), as well as the country code selection, before the submit function can pass. The current implementation validated the country code input against the phone input, but is not validated itself as far as being selected. How can I set a rule that the country code must be selected, and warn the user(highlighting the dropdown area, or a message under the text input) that the dropdown must be selected?

**HTML**

```
<form id="phone">
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn">'+ '
            <button id="label" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span id="areaCodes">+1</span><span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="areaCodes" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#" id="1">+1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" id="44">+44</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control phone" name="phone" aria-label="..." placeholder="Your phone number" type="text"> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input class="btn btn-default submit" type="submit">SUBMIT</input>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// Load dialog on page load
//$('#basic-modal-content').modal();

// Load dialog on click
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
    return false;
});

$("#1, #44").click(function (e) {
    $("#label").html("+" + $(this).attr("id") + " <span class='caret'></span>");
    var phone = $('input[name="phone"]');
    if ($(this).attr("id") == '1') {
        phone.rules('remove', 'phoneUK');
        phone.rules('add', {
            phoneUS: true
        });
    } else {
        phone.rules('remove', 'phoneUS');
        phone.rules('add', {
            phoneUK: true
        });
    }
});

$("#areaCodes li").click(function () {
    $("#label").text($($(this).find("a")).text())
    //removes isSelected class
    $("#areaCodes li a").removeClass("isSelected");
    //add isSlected Class to clicked element
    $($(this).find('a')).addClass("isSelected")
});

$('.phone').on('input', function (event) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
});

$("#phone").validate({
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.insertAfter($(element).parent('div'));
    },
    rules: {
        phone: {
            required: true,
            phoneUS: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        phone: {
            phoneUS: "Please enter a valid US number",
            phoneUK: "Please enter a valid UK number"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/textMessage/' + $("#areaCodes .isSelected").text() + $('input[name="phone"]').val(),
            method: "GET",
            success: function () {
                console.log(form);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

**Current version: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/1s970kzk/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Inside  `$("#areaCodes li").click(function ()` add `blur` function to the input, so it will try to validate the input

```
$("#areaCodes li").click(function () {
    $("#label").text($($(this).find("a")).text())
    //removes isSelected class
    $("#areaCodes li a").removeClass("isSelected");
    //add isSlected Class to clicked element
    $($(this).find('a')).addClass("isSelected");

    //add this
    $('.phone').blur();
});
```

I use .phone here, should be an ID #something, but require you add id to input with class phone

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/1s970kzk/2/)

Updated Answer:

The problem is that, I think, because your list `li` is not an input, so you can't attach validation there with '`jQuery Validation`'. The other work around for this, I can think only 2 at this moment, 
first checking whether there is li.selected on submit function, 
or 
the second, add custom validation on phone

rules:

```
rules: {
    phone: {
        listMustHaveValue: true,
        required: true,
        phoneUS: true

    },
```

new method on validator:

```
 $.validator.addMethod(
        "listMustHaveValue", 
        function(value, element) {
            var liselected = $('#areaCodes .isSelected');
            return liselected .length > 0;
        },
        "List must have value"
    );
```

Update 2:

And no. 3, is ***changing*** `ul list` to `select option`, so you can have validation there, simply by stating required is true

Comment: Hmm, the issue is that the user needs to have a warning(similar to the numerical input warning), that they haven't selected a country code.

Comment: The problem with using a dropdown select(as I've done with this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/1s970kzk/3/), is that you can't select the second option `+44`, nor can the value get grabbed.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a remote service(https://www.wipmania.com/) that does country detection based on IP.

```
$('.phoneNumber').on('input', function (event) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
});
$("#phone").submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var that = this,
    country = $(this).find("#countryCodes").val(),
    phoneNumber = $(this).find(".phone").val(),
    callUrl = "/textMessage/" + country + phoneNumber,
    ukValid = new RegExp(/^[0-9]{10,11}$/),
    usValid = new RegExp(/^\d{10}$/);
console.log("phone# = ", phoneNumber);

function callService() {
    initialFormText();
    $.get(callUrl, function (data) {
        //console.log( "sent" );
    })
        .done(function () {
        //console.log( "success" );
    })
        .fail(function () {
        //console.log( "call error" );
    })
        .always(function () {
        //console.log( "finished" );
        $(that).addClass('hide').next('.success').addClass('active');
    });
}

function initialFormText() {
    $('.mb-35').html("Enter your phone number and we’ll send a link to your iPhone");
    $('.mb-35').css({
        'color': '#86888b'
    });
    }

    if ((country === "44") && (ukValid.test(phoneNumber))) {
        if ((phoneNumber.length > 10) && (phoneNumber[0] === "0")) {
            callService();
        } else if (phoneNumber.length < 11) {
            callService();
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.reload-form').click()
            }, 100);
            $(this).find('.mb-35').html("The number you have entered is incorrect format. Please enter correct phone number. ");
            $(this).find('.mb-35').css({
                'color': 'red'
            });
        }

    } else if (usValid.test(phoneNumber)) {
        callService();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.reload-form').click()
        }, 100);
        $(this).find('.mb-35').html("The number you have entered is incorrect format. Please enter correct phone number. ");
        $(this).find('.mb-35').css({
            'color': 'red'
        });

        console.log("number is invalid");
    }
    return;
});


    //country detection==================
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?",
            dataType: "jsonp"
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (data) {

                if (data.address.continent === "North America") {

                    $($('.dropdown-menu').find('button').find('span').get(0)).html("US (+1)");
                    $('#countryCodes').val('1');

                    $('.dropdown-menu').each(function () {
                        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').find('li').each(function () {
                            if ($(this).attr("data-value") === "1") {
                                $(this).addClass('disabled');
                            } else {
                                $(this).removeClass('disabled');
                            }
                        });
                    })

                } else if (data.address.continent === "Europe") {

                    $($('.dropdown-menu').find('button').find('span').get(0)).html("UK (+44)");
                    $('#countryCodes').val('44');

                    $('.dropdown-menu').each(function () {
                        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').find('li').each(function () {
                            if ($(this).attr("data-value") === "44") {
                                $(this).addClass('disabled');
                            } else {
                                $(this).removeClass('disabled');
                            }
                        });
                    })

                } else {
                    $($('.dropdown-menu').find('button').find('span').get(0)).html("US   
         (+1)");
                    $('#countryCodes').val('1');

                    $('.dropdown-menu').each(function () {
                        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').find('li').each(function () {
                            if ($(this).attr("data-value") === "1") {
                                $(this).addClass('disabled');
                            } else {
                                $(this).removeClass('disabled');
                            }
                        });
                    })
                }

            }

        });
    });
```